# How to show this identity: $\delta'(-x) = -\delta'(x)$

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I was wondering how to prove the following property regarding the derivative of the Dirac delta function: $$\delta'(-x) = -\delta'(x)$$

I try to do it by multiplying both sides by some function $f(x)$ and then integrating by parts like so:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta'(-x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-f(x)\delta'(x)dx$$
$$f(x)\delta(-x)\rvert_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'(x)\delta(-x)dx = -[f(x)\delta(x)\rvert_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'(x)\delta(x)dx]$$
$$0 - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'(x)\delta(-x)dx = 0 + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'(x)\delta(x)dx$$

Then using the property that $\delta(-x) = \delta(x)$:
$$-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'(x)\delta(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'(x)\delta(x)dx$$

And here's where I keep getting stuck due to the differences in signs. Is there a mistake in my integration, or is there some other property of the Dirac delta function that I'm just not utilizing?

Comment: What shall $\delta : \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be ?

Comment: @Falrach. It's the [Dirac delta "function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) (rather a distribution).

Comment: Your mistake is that $\delta'(-x)$ is the distributional derivative of $-\delta(-x)$ not $\delta(-x)$ (see my comment below to see why)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\delta(x)=\delta(-x)$, so the result follows from the chain rule.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I never thought to use differentiation to prove that identity. I was always under the assumption that Dirac delta properties had to be proven by applying a test function then integrating by parts.

Comment: @D.Ashton You can define $\langle T(-x), \varphi \rangle = \langle T, \varphi(-x) \rangle$, then $\langle \delta'(-x), \varphi \rangle = \langle \delta', \varphi(-x) \rangle = - \varphi'(0)$, then show this is compatible with the chain rule. Otherwise note $\delta$ is an even distribution : take $\varphi_n(x) = n e^{-\pi n^2 x^2}$, then $\varphi_n \to \delta$ and $\varphi_n(-.) \to \delta$. Thus $\varphi_n' \to \delta'$ has to be an odd distribution.

Comment: The chain rule must of course be justified. Try to do it, @D.Ashton!